# How do i make the program jump back to input (cout)

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, if-statement

can someone help me jump back to the start of program (cout). The expected result should be: result printed --> Do you want to start again? (y/n). if answer = y then go to the start, if answer = n, then close the program.

Here's the code:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>

class myClass {
private:
    int var[3];
    char response;
public:
    void input() {
        std::cout << "Please enter a number " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> var[0];
        std::cout << "Please enter a range " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> var[1];
    }

    void calc() {

        for (var[2] = 1; var[2] <= var[1]; var[2]++)
            std::cout << var[2] * var[1] << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {

    myClass MyObj;
    MyObj.input();
    MyObj.calc();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add a while loop in main?

Comment: @AlanBirtles int main?

Comment: enclose your `.input()` and `.calc` in a `while (input != 'q')` loop; print result and get input at the bottom of the loop

Comment: @Jack sorry i dont understand, can you provide code example?

Answer (score 0):

Hi man you can enclose your input() and calc function with a while loop like this:

```
char flag = 'y';
while (flag != 'n') {
MyObj.input();
MyObj.calc();
std::cout << "Do you want to start again ? (y / n)";
std::cin >> flag;
}
```

I think this will work for u